# Updating records in MongoDB through pymongo leads to deletion of most of them

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Im working with a remote mongodb database in my python code.The code accessing the database and the database itself are on two different machines. The pymongo module version im using is 1.9+.
The script consists of the following code:

```
 for s in coll.find({ "somefield.a_date" : { "$exists":False },
                               "somefield.b_date" : { "$exists":False }}):
            original = s['details']['c_date']

            utc = from_tz.localize(original).astimezone(pytz.utc)

            s['details']['c_date'] = utc

            if str(type(s['somefield'])) != "<type 'dict'>":
                     s['somefield'] = {}

            s['somefield']['b_date'] = datetime.utcnow()

            coll.update({ '_id' : s['_id'] }, s );
```

After running this code, a strange thing happened. There were millions of records in the collection initially and after running the script,just 29% of the total records remained, the rest were automatically deleted. Is there any known issue with PyMongo driver version 1.9+ ?
What could have been other reasons for this and any ways i can find out what exactly happened ?

Comment: Instead of `if str(type(s['somefield'])) != "<type 'dict'>":` you should use `if isinstance(s['somefield'], dict):` -- it's more readable and more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

> What could have been other reasons for this and any ways i can find out what exactly happened ?

The first thing to check is *"were there any exceptions"*?

In `coll.update()`, you are not setting the `safe` variable. If there is an exception on the `update`, it will not be thrown.

In your code you not do not catch exceptions (which is suggested) and your update does not check for exceptions, so you have no way of knowing what's going on.

The second thing to check is *"how are you counting"*?

The `update` command can "blank out" data, but it cannot delete data (or change an `_id`).

Do you have a copy of the original data? Can you run your code on a small number of those 10 or 100 and see what's happening?

**What you describe is not normal with any of the MongoDB drivers**. We definitely need more data to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try running the code on a smaller set of the data and ill get back with the results.Also,as you suggested ill use the safe variable this time and add exception handling to the code.

Comment: Im counting the records using db.collection_name.count(). Isnt that the right way to count data ?. Also, what is the meaning of update blanking out data but not deleting it ?

Comment: A badly formed `update` can result in bad data in the document. However the `_id` cannot change, so a badly formed update cannot "delete" the document. How is the testing coming? Do you have a test case that is regularly deleting data?

Comment: Yes `db.collection_name.count()` is the correct way to count data. However, if you're using sharding, you have to issue that call from the `mongos` so it's important to double check that you're connecting to the right place.