# Inconsistent results being returned by mongodb find query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I ran the following query on a collection in my mongodb database.

`db.coll.find({field_name:{$exists:true}}).count()` and it returned 2437185. The total records reported by `db.coll.find({}).count()` is 2437228 .

Now when i run the query `db.coll.find({field_name:{$exists:false}}).count()` , instead of returning 43 it returned 0.

I have the following two questions :

1. Does the above scenario mean that the data in my collection has become corrupt ?.
2. I had posted a question earlier about this at ( [Updating records in MongoDB through pymongo leads to deletion of most of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7083291)). The person who replied said that updating data in mongo db could blank out the data but not delete it. What does that mean ?.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're running into the issue reported at [SERVER-1587](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1587). What version of MongoDB are you using? If it is less than 1.9.0, you can use the following as a work-around:

```
db.coll.find({field_name: {$not: {$exists: true}}}).count()
```

As for the other question, "blanking out" in this case means that an update can change the value of or unset any or all fields in a document, but can't remove the document itself. The only way to remove a document is with `remove()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried db.coll.find({field_name: {$not: {$exists: true}}}).count() , it still returns 0 !. As for the mongodb version, when i run db.version() at the shell it shows 1.6.1. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Are you able to upgrade mongo? 1.6.x is fairly old. 1.8.x is the current production series, and 2.0 is due in the next few weeks. "odd-numbered" releases (1.7.x, 1.9.x) are development releases not intended for production use.